# What happened to Kurama?

Tags: naruto

So it's been a couple of years since Naruto ended, and I don't think the author answered this question/mystery within the Narutoverse: Isn't a Bijuu supposed to die after the host's death? How exactly did Minato have 50% left within him, and why did this chakra not return to Naruto?

If this was answered in some interview or solved, could you direct me to them? This could be counted as plotholes or something that was left to reader's discretion by Kishimoto-sensei.

Comment: Asking multiple questions in one post is not recommended, unless they are _very_ closely related. Please read the [tour] and the [ask] pages, those may be helpful.

Comment: so i was wondering if an exception could be made , since these all questions seperately are pretty vague ? and make sense to be answered since they are part of one universe? should i wait for a moderator to check or break it down right now?

Comment: You can _Begin_ thinking about breaking it down, but since I'm not a frequent user of this site, I'd say you should also consult other people. Why not try [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-)?

Comment: @Shashi456 the problem with asking multiple unconnected question (excluding universe connection) like this is that people tend not to answer all of them in the one answer. for instance with 1 and 5 someone can post an answer for 1 but not on 5 and someone might answer 5 but not 1, which answer is correct then?

Comment: So if I edit it will it be put off hold?

Comment: you can edited it and if it's on topic we can reopen your question

Comment: What about now @Memor-X

Comment: @Shashi456 While your post is better than previously, you are still asking many questions in a single post. Don't hesitate to ask multiple questions in multiple posts rather than trying to keep everything together. But still, it is better now than before :)

Comment: Done finally I guess xD

Comment: Sound fine for me, I voted in favor of the reopen

Comment: Matt @Memor-X Maroon , is it okay now

Comment: @Shashi456 to me yes and i have already cast a reopen vote

Comment: I think the part about the Biju dying when the Jinchuriki dies was mention when Naruto got Kurama sealed in him or when Kakashi killed Rin. Either way, I think the Biju does die but it's only temporarily apparently (I think Kushina said this, not sure though).

Comment: Yeah so if it does , shouldn't it have happened that the other 50% should have returned to Naruto ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are good, but they don't really point out the main reason why Yin Kurama did not reincarnate.

The [Reaper Death Seal, or Dead Demon Consuming Seal](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Dead_Demon_Consuming_Seal) is a special kind of seal. It not only kills you, but your soul is sealed inside the Reapers Stomach. By doing so, you are cut off from the Pure land.

From the entry on [Bijuu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tailed_Beast)

> Because the tailed beasts are pure chakra, they cannot actually be killed; if they or their jinchūriki die, their chakra will re-coalesce in time. In addition, if a large portion of a tailed beast's chakra is separated from it, that chakra becomes a separate, sentient copy of the tailed beast.

This is the 2 bits of most important information here. First, Kurama was split in half, and the Yin half was sealed in Minato. This half was then taken into the Reapers Stomach, where it was sealed.

Now, as noted, they can not die. So why didn't the Yin half revive? Simple, Because they don't actually revive. As noted in the quote, their Chakra once dispersed due to death of some kind, will coalesce, giving them form again. However, the half sealed in Minato's soul was taken into the Reapers Stomach, and there it was sealed. There is no way for it to escape, and so it cant merge back with Yang Kurama, nor can it coalesce into its own half. Bijuu can not easily escape from their Jinchuriki, and the Reaper Death seal is like an incredibly powerful version of that.

so Tl;DR, Bijuu don't die, ever. They just disperse and coalesce. However, Yin Kurama was sealed into the Reapers Stomach, and not only could not escape, but didn't even disperse in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

When Minato used the Reaper Death (Dead Demon Consuming) Seal he essentially split Kurama into two parts:

1. Yang Kurama
2. Yin Kurama

Each half [Kurama](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nine-Tails) have their own conscience, making them two separate entities.

> Later, when Naruto and Minato bumped fists, Yin and Yang-Kurama came in contact with each other, with Yang-Kurama greeting its other half casually and asking it to share its chakra, which led Yin-Kurama to note that asking itself for chakra was an odd situation

The reason for separating the charka was because an infant would not be able to withstand the power of Kurama if he had contained both sides of his chakra.

> Since Kurama's chakra was too immense to be sealed within an infant like Naruto, Minato first used the Dead Demon Consuming Seal to separate and seal its Yin half within himself and then prepared the Eight Trigrams Seal to imprison the Yang half within Naruto

Furthermore, Minato, knowing the consequence of performing the [Reaper Death (Dead Demon Consuming) Seal](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Dead_Demon_Consuming_Seal), seals Yin Kurama within himself.

> When Minato uses it, he seals only the Nine-Tails' yin chakra, leaving its yang chakra alone; this sealing of its yin chakra into himself makes him its jinchūriki.

The consequence? Death.... kind of.

> For a few moments afterwards the summoner can continue moving and speaking, allowing them to finish any lingering business they may have. Shortly afterwards the Shinigami will consume their soul and the soul of their target(s), ending their life. The souls of those trapped within the Shinigami's stomach cannot enter the Pure Land and are destined to fight with their victims for all eternity

With Kurama being split into two separate entities, one half was trapped within Minato while the other half lived on and was sealed within Naruto. Because the souls are trapped within the Shinigami's stomach, destined to fight each other, this also explains why Minato is able to use [Nine Tails Chakra Mode](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nine-Tails_Chakra_Mode).

Comment: typo in the last paragraph "Because the souls are trapped within the Pure Land"

Comment: @Ryan:  Next time you could suggest an edit for it, too.  The site's pretty flexible like that.

Answer (score 2):

During the Nine-Tails attack, Minato divided Kurama's chakra into two parts. Reason is that Kurama has a huge amount of chakra that **couldn't be sealed inside baby Naruto**.

So Minato used the Reaper Death Seal to seal one half of the chakra inside him as there was nowhere else to seal Kurama, and not sealing the other half will create further problems (like more destruction to the village).

Now in case of Reaper Death Seal, the soul is trapped inside the belly of the death god, so nothing can escape it. When Orochimaru released the trapped souls, everyone came out. I think this is why Kabuto never reanimated any of the hokages. And as Kurama was trapped inside Minato, so that chakra never escaped.